# Using sed or awk to filter a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with 1000 IP address in the format, after the 4 octets is the source port which i need filtered. I am a bit new to bash scripting so struggling to grep the IP address filtering the port number. Any suggestions on how I used `sed` or `awk` to filter the port number will be really appreciated.

```
192.168.100.1.111  
192.168.200.10.111  
192.168.200.128.501  
192.168.150.5.300
```

**Output desired**

```
192.168.100.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too easy.

```bash
awk -F'.' '{print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4}' < /tmp/ipaddresses.txt
```

Comment: That was super easy, if there are any repeated IP's in the list, is there any string i can add to filter the IP's, only one instance of the IP should be shown.

Comment: There's more than one way to do that: `awk -F'.' '{print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4}' < /tmp/ipaddresses.txt | uniq` or `awk -F'.' '{print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4}' < /tmp/ipaddresses.txt | sort -u`.

Comment: even easier with `cut -d. -f1-4`

Comment: Also with `awk '!seen[$0]++'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the below command:-

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' your_ip_address.txt > filtered_ip_address.txt
```

It will remove the last dot along with following string.

For example:-

```
 echo 192.168.100.1.111 | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

Will output:-

```
 192.168.100.1
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand regex a bit thought i am new, are we not matching any dot with the the regex "^."  ?

Comment: That is for searching the last dot. Once found delete remaining string from that dot onward.

Comment: Sure thank you, i tried this earlier but didnt work  which had a common source port of 153 sed -E '/^_.153_$/d'

Comment: try with my option `sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'` it will definitely work.

Comment: Yup that worked, by the way if there are any repeated IP's in the file can filter that too in the file using the same expression?

Comment: Yes it will do.

Comment: It doesnt seem to filter duplicate IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` example:

```
your_port=111
awk -F\. -v port=$your_port '$NF==port{$NF="";sub(/.$/, "");print}' OFS='.' file
```

If you just want to remove the ports:

```
sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//' your_file
```

Or in `awk`:

```
awk -F\. '{$NF="";sub(/.$/, "")}1' OFS='.' your_file
```

To avoid duplicates in **just one process**:

```
awk -F\. '{$NF="";sub(/.$/, "")}!a[$0]++' OFS='.' your_file
```

Comment: Since OP wants only one row why not? awk -F\. '{$NF="";sub(/.$/, "")}$4=="1"' OFS='.' file

Answer (score 0):

Remember that calling `awk` or `sed` is calling a new program, while Bash is already running. Instead you could filter your input directly in Bash:

```
$ while read url; do echo ${url%.*}; done <<EOL
129.168.100.1.111
1291.168.200.10.111
EOL

129.168.100.1
1291.168.200.10
```

That is

```
while read url
do
  echo ${url%.*}
done < urls.txt
```

**References**

The **parameter expansion** (see `man bash`) `{url%.*}` uses the variable `$url` and strips (`%`) everything which matches the pattern `.*`.  Note that pattern matching is different from regular expressions. In particular pattern matching has simpler syntax. That is `.` matches the literal character `.`, and `*` matches any string. Pattern matching is most commonly know for filename patterns as in `*.txt`, etc.

```
${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}
       Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
       a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
       a  trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the
       result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter  with
       the  shortest  matching  pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest
       matching pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter  is  @
       or  *,  the  pattern  removal operation is applied to each posi-
       tional parameter in turn, and the  expansion  is  the  resultant
       list.   If  parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or
       *, the pattern removal operation is applied to  each  member  of
       the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, most probably why my regexp didnt work as i was trying pattern matching.